# how to show error msg in my jsp page as a popup alert

Tags: java, javascript, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am using java Spring MVC,i want show this msg for user..
This my part of controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/DeleteTeam", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String editDeleteRecodes(@ModelAttribute NewTeams newTeams, BindingResult result, @RequestParam String action, Map<String, Object> map){     
        Teams teams = new Teams();
        teams.setTeamID(newTeams.getTeamID());
        try{
            teamService.delete(teams);
        }catch (DataIntegrityViolationException ex){
            map.put("error", "Frist Delete Releases");

        }

        return "redirect:/";


    }
```

Comment: using ajax call. then you send your data using ajax response.

Comment: can u explain..i have no idea how to put that in jsp..thanks lot

Answer (score 1):

set one attribute if you want to alert and manage it accordingly. then check in your jsp for that attribute whether it is null or having some value if so simple alert `<script>alert("Your alert")</script>`

**EDIT:**

on server side set attribute like

```
request.setAtrribute("error", "error");
```

on your jsp page 
check for attribute like

```
if(request.getAttribute("error")!=null){
<script>alert("hi")</script>
}
```

Comment: can u explain..i have no idea how to put that in jsp..thanks lot

Comment: <%        request.setAtrribute("error", "error");


if(request.getAttribute("error")!=null){
<script>alert("hi")</script>
}
%>    how to write scripts tag in jsp